# Enable Agent Database Mail - TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-mail, sql-server-agent

I have several new servers that need Database Mail configured on them.  I found the TechNet article describing how to add the profile and account via procedure calls, but is there a way to enable database mail and select the profile for the SQL Agent in the same manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following T-SQL will enable Database Mail in SQL Server Agent:

```
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_set_sqlagent_properties @email_save_in_sent_folder=1
GO
EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
    N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\SQLServerAgent', N'UseDatabaseMail', 
    N'REG_DWORD', 1
GO
EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
    N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\SQLServerAgent', N'DatabaseMailProfile', 
    N'REG_SZ', N'<profilename>'
GO
```

For future reference, you can easily determine this by expanding the "SQL Server Agent" node in SQL Server Management Studio's Object Explorer pane.  Then right-click on "SQL Server Agent", click "Properties", select "Alert System", enter the appropriate details, and click on "Script":

[image]

Comment: I know of the GUI approach, but was wanting to do it all in a script so I could quickly jump from server to server.  Your script did the trick.

Comment: I was trying to point out that you can determine many scripts by using the "Script" button at the top of most dialogs in SQL Server Management Studio.  But, either way you're welcome for the answer!

Comment: Ha, missed the script part.  Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: My pleasure.  It's an easily overlooked, but handy-as-hell feature.  I've used it many times to learn how SQL Server Management Studio does things internally.